# UINavigationController initWithRootVC: how to force the VC to load?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I created a view controller and then create a navigation controller with:

```
initWithRootViewController:
```

then I observed that it calls `pushViewController:animated:`, since I am using my own `UINavigationController` subclass, I overwrite `pushViewController:animated:`:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    // do something with the VC
}
```

The problem is, immediately after

```
[super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
```

the `viewController.isViewLoaded` is NO, so I cannot actually do what I want, is there a way to force a VC to be loaded, when it is used as the root VC of a navigation controller?

Thanks!

edit, below is the code:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"" bundle:nil];
MyNavController *nav = [[MyNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

self.revealViewController.frontViewController = nav;
```

Comment: You shouldn't override pushViewController:animated: in your subclass. I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but you don't have to do anything to get the root view controller's view to load -- it should load automatically. Please post the code where you create your root view controller and the navigation controller.

Comment: What view do you expect to see? vc will just show a blank screen when it loads because you haven't put anything into its view. BTW, there isn't a method called initWithNib:bundle:, it's initWithNibName:bundle

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer in the Apple documentation

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This
>   class is not intended for subclassing.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Access view before pushing viewController.

[viewController view];//this will load your view
[super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
```

Comment: +1 [viewController view]! So simple, so obvious, how did I miss it?